# need to pass an array with an object inside it

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, redux

- In my post request I need to pass an array with an object inside it.
- when I tried to add new properties inside an object its adding.
- but when I tried to add when an object is present inside an array its not adding.
  I have sportsvalues as array `const sportsValues = [{ ...values }];`
- I am trying to build something like this, so that I can pass in the api
  `[
  {
  "playerName": 3,
  "playerHeight": 1
  }
  ]`
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet below.

```or-tag-here
export function sports(values) {
    const sportsValues = [{ ...values }];
    sportsValues.push(playerName:'3');
    console.log("sportsValues--->", sportsValues);

    // sportsValues.playerName = 3//'';
    // sportsValues.playerHeight = 1//'';
    console.log("after addition sportsValues--->", sportsValues);
    console.log("after deletion sportsValues--->", sportsValues);

    return dispatch => {
        axios
            .post(`${url}/sport`, sportsValues)
            .then(() => {
                return;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(`Error\n${error}`);
            });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sportsValues` is an array of objects, you can push new object into it. Check out code below.

```js
const sportsValues = [];
sportsValues.push({ 
  playerName:'3',
  playerHeight: 1,
});

console.log(sportsValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but here's some pointers:

If you're trying to update the object that's inside the array, you first have to select the object inside the array, then update it's attribute:

`sportsValues[0].playerName = 3`

although, I recommend building the object correctly first, then passing it to the array, it makes it a little easier to understand in my opinion:

```
const sportsValues = [];
const firstValue = { ...values };
firstValue.playerName = '3';
sportsValues.push(firstValue);
```

or

```
const firstValue = { ...values };
firstValue.playerName = '3';
const sportsValues = [firstValue];
```

or

```
const sportsValues = [{
  ...values,
  playername: '3',
}];
```

if you're trying to add a new object to the array, you can do this:

```
const sportsValues = [{ ...values }];
sportsValues.push({ playerName: '3' });
etc...
```

Array.push adds a new item to the array, so in your code, you're going to have 2 items because you assign 1 item at the beginning and then push a new item:

```
const ar = [];
// []
ar.push('item');
// ['item']
ar.push({ text: 'item 2' });
// ['item', { text: 'item 2' }]
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
export function sports(values) {
  const sportsValues = [{ ...values }];
  sportsValues.push(playerName:'3');
  let playerName='3' 
  sportsValues.playerName= playerName; // you can bind in this way
  console.log("sportsValues--->", sportsValues);

  return dispatch => {
    axios
        .post(`${url}/sport`, sportsValues)
        .then(() => {
            return;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(`Error\n${error}`);
        });
  };
}
```